# How to change internet login information using a remote connection

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have this problem. I have a computer at my university. In order to connect to the internet inside the university, one needs to go to the login webpage and enter his user/pass. Currently, I am connected to my computer at university from home using a remote desktop software (anydesk). However, I wish to log in to the internet from the university with a different account. To do so, I need to sign out of my account, then log in with the other account. But if I log out the remote connection will go offline. Is there a script or tool which can help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

However, when you log out of that current account, your connection to the home will be disconnected, but you may be able to execute a scheduling task that is able to execute a trigger by logging into the Internet login page and then entering the second password. Your problem may be resolved.